# Numerical simulation of water layer over terrain

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics, simulation

I'm looking for a grid-based numerical method that allows simulating water over a grid-based terrain, presumably something like shallow water equations. I have a square grid of terrain elevation values, and I want a numerical method that evolves water level (values of height of water layer on the same grid) in real-time. I don't mind if the method is inaccurate in some respects, but I want it to be mass-conserving and be able to deal with absence of water (i.e. dry land) without any artifacts.

The methods I've found that are closest to what I mean but don't suit all my needs:

- *Stable Fluids* by Jos Stam - doesn't seem to incorporate both water height & terrain height, seems to only consider density of some solvent
- *Real-Time Erosion Using Shallow Water Simulation* by Bedrich Beneš - the best I've found so far, but it lacks mass conservation, and it is not entirely clear how to restore it in a reasonable way

Comment: Possible the engineering site might get better results?

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, it well may be. I asked on physics first & got zero attention. Didn't consider engineering, thank you for this suggestion.

Comment: Consider also scicomp's stackexchange.

Comment: This is just a random suggestion, but in circuit simulation a problem some years ago was charge conservation (important for simulation of FETs). Very loosely the approach was to model charge directly (rather than other related variables), the actual methods for integration are still fairly standard. Not sure if this even applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the use of finite volume schemes, as these are rather easy to implement and they provide physically meaningful and accurate results. See for instance the articles [1, 2] as an entry point to the relevant literature (i.e., see also references therein).

[1] RJ LeVeque, DL George: High-resolution finite volume methods for the shallow water equations with bathymetry and dry states, *Advanced Numerical Models for Simulating Tsunami Waves and Runup*, pp. 43-73, World Scientific, 2008. [doi:10.1142/9789812790910_0002](https://doi.org/10.1142/9789812790910_0002)

[2] A Kurganov: Finite-volume schemes for shallow-water equations, *Acta Numerica* 27 (2018), pp. 289-351. [doi:10.1017/S0962492918000028](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0962492918000028)

Comment: I've dived into the second paper and it seems to be precisely what I need, or at least an excellent entry point thereof. Thank you.